# Picking problems with collada loaded models in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, collada, picking

I'm experiencing picking problems when loading a collada model in ThreeJS. The picking example for cubes works fine. Loading a collada model works as well.
However it seems that for picking collada object I need to pick well above the 3D object. As picking works for the cube I cannot figure out why it is not working for collada objects (export from SketchUp). Does anyone have a good example where it is possible to load a collada model and pick the individual objects? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792867/select-collada-objects-by-mouse-click-in-three-js ?

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. My GWT application creates an HTML component above the ThreeJS content. I guess window.innerheight or something like that goes wrong. Thanks anyway for the help!